# faded menu bar wiith js hover and ie 8.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Hi can any one help me with this,

I have a  menu bar with a faded background black to grey. when I hover over a category I wish it to turn white (which it does) when I move the mouse away I want it to return to the faded menu. I have this set in the js file

```
  $(this).find("a:first").stop().animate({
        color: '#04660b',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },300
  );
},
function() {
  $(this).find("a:first").stop().animate({
       color: '#ffffff',
       background: ' '
   },300
 );
}
```

);

This works in IE 9, Chrome but will not work in IE 8, any ideas would be welcomed. the original version of the had backgroundColor: '#00ee00' which worked fine but noy what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the backgroundColor and not the background??? or setting it to the original one..

```
  $(this).find("a:first").stop().animate({
        color: '#04660b',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },300
  );
},
function() {
  $(this).find("a:first").stop().animate({
       color: '#ffffff',
       backgroundColor: ' '
   },300
 );
}
);
```